# Is it possible to search the data with field type droplist ,droplink or tag tree list

Tags: sxa, solr, sxa-search

I m using sitecore 9.0.1 with sxa 1.7,i have default sxa search component and wants to know whether we can search the data with field type droplist ,droplink ,tag tree list etc..Without adding any filters.

If possible how can we achieve that?
Current search box is giving results for the single line text data type.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default SXA comes with a computed field `sxacontent` which is aggregating all texts from all fields of an item and uses the implementation in `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.AggregatedContent`. It is configured in  `\App_Config\Include\z.Foundation.Overrides\Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Solr.config`.  Thanks to this there is no need to configure fields and other stuff, you just drop Search Box and Search Results on the page and search is working.

If I understand correctly from your question you would like to index content from the items selected in the droplink, tree list fields? You can add your own custom implementation if you override the configuration node `<field fieldName="sxacontent" returnType="textCollection" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.AggregatedContent, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search">`

Comment: Can you please explain what kind of changes need to make to that node in the config file because the said changes is already present in the config file.@Cristi Vulturar

Comment: After you implement your custom implementation class you need to patch replace the value in type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.AggregatedContent, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" with type="YourCustom.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.AggregatedContent, YourCustom.Foundation.Search"